# I am trying to add size constraints to a button in Xcode 14. It appears that the constraints have been added but I see no physical change

Tags: ios, uikit, uibutton, autolayout

[Screenshot from Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt0Ui.png)

(I am using a tutorial from Udacity that was made in 2016, so the Xcode is different. I have followed the steps in the tutorial but I am not getting the same result).

I have added the constraints using auto layout but the size of the button did not reduce.

Comment: This isn't about SwiftUI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask]. What is creating the circle? What image are you using? What is the result you are expecting?